# Spark ignores configurations for executor and driver memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to increase memory allocation for my executors and drivers in Spark, but I have the strange feeling that Spark is ignoring my configurations.

I'm using the following commands:

> spark-submit spark_consumer.py --driver-memory=10G
>   --executor-memory=5G --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-XX:+UseParallelGC
>   -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps'

My initialization code is

```
class SparkRawConsumer:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.sparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

        self.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        self.sqlContext = SQLContext(self.sparkContext)
```

Theoretically, I should see that my driver program has total available 10GB of memory. However, I see this in my Spark UI (where my memory available is less than 400MB):
[image]

Why is Spark ignoring the configurations I am passing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that I had specified the ordering of parameters incorrectly. Typing `spark-submit --help` clearly specifies an ordering for the input parameters to `spark-submit`:

```
Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file | R file> [app arguments]
```

Once I changed the ordering of the parameters, I was able to increase memory on my PySpark app:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 8G --executor-memory 8G spark_consumer.py
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 differents way to define spark configuration

1) spark-env.sh

2) spark-submit parameter

3) hard coding sparkConf, exemple : `sparkConf.set("spark.driver.memory","10G");`

the priority are : hard coding > spark-submit > spark.env ;

if you think your parameter are overwrite by something else you can check it with : `sparkConf.getOption("spark.driver.memory");`

if you want to be sure that your options are not overwrite hard code it.

you can see all options here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: I don't believe you can set memory configurations within the application. I've tried all three of your approaches, and `spark-submit` is the only one I can get working currently. Could you provide some samples of hard coding in your options?